# Show that $\left( \frac{k-1}{k}\right)^{\delta^{2/5}(1-\delta)n/2}k^{\delta^{1/2}n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for $\delta>0$ sufficiently small

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, asymptotics

Suppose that $k$ and $n$ are positive integers. Assume that $k$ is fixed. I am trying to figure out why $$\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^{\delta^{2/5}(1-\delta)n/2}k^{\delta^{1/2}n} \to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$ for $\delta>0$ sufficiently small.

The key is to try to show that
$$\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^{\delta^{2/5}(1-\delta)/2}k^{\delta^{1/2}}<1$$
for $\delta>0$ sufficiently small, but I can't even seem to figure that out. Is there a straightforward way to see this? Thank you.

Comment: For fixed $k$, when $\delta \to 0$, then last expression tends to $1$, so, may be, your aim is unreachable. Or we need some more info.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, but $\delta$ itself can never be zero.

Comment: @zkutch I asked Wolfram Alpha to solve the last inequality when $k=2$. I tried to paste the link here, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sarah Can you show that the derivative of the left hand side in the last inequality with respect to $\delta$ is negative for all $k$? If you can do that, you will have proven that the left hand side approaches $1$ from below as $\delta\rightarrow 0^+$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I also tried taking the derivative with respect to $\delta$, but the expression I obtain as a result is more difficult to work with.

Comment: since $k \ge 1$, we can also write the inequality as $$\frac{k-1}{k^{1-2\delta^{1/10}/(1-\delta)}} < 1$$. Compressing all the $\delta$ dependence into a single exponent seems useful.

Comment: Also, do we want to find a $\delta$ such that for all $k$ that limit holds, or are we trying to show that for each $k$ there exists some $\delta$ (not necessarily the same) such that the limit holds?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I edited my post and added the fact that $k$ is a fixed positive integers. For fixed $k$ we want to show that there exists a $\delta$ such that the second inequality is less than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the inequality is equivalent to
$$
\frac{k-1}{k^{1-2\delta^{1/10}/(1-\delta)}}<1.
$$
Since the statement is clearly true for $k = 1$, we may assume $k-1 >0$. At this point we can solve for the $\delta$ dependence, getting
$$
\frac{2\delta^{1/10}}{1-\delta}  < 1-\frac{\ln (k-1)}{\ln k}.
$$
Since the RHS is positive and the LHS continuously maps $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$, there must be some $\delta^*\in (0,1)$ such that the two are equal. Since the LHS is also a strictly increasing function of $\delta$ that is zero when $\delta = 0$, therefore there must be some $\delta$ with $ 0 < \delta < \delta^*$ such that $2\delta^{1/10}/(1-\delta) < 2{\delta^*}^{1/10}/(1-d) = 1-\ln(k-1)/\ln(k)$.